# How Do Callbacks work in Non-blocking Design?

Tags: multithreading, scala, asynchronous, callback, nonblocking

Looked at a few other questions but didn't quite find what I was looking for. Im using Scala but my questions is very high level and so is hopefully agnostic of any languages.

---

A regular scenario:

1. `Thread A` runs a function and there is some blocking work to be done (say a DB call).
2. The function has some non-blocking code (eg. `Async` block in Scala) to cause some sort of 'worker' `Thread B` (in a different pool) to pick up the I/O task.
3. The method in `Thread A` completes returning a Future which will eventually contain the result and `Thread A` is returned to its pool to quickly pick up another request to process.

**Q1. Some thread somewhere usually has to wait?**

My understanding of non-blocking architectures is that the common approach is to still have some Thread waiting/blocking on the I/O work somewhere - its just a case of having different pools which have access to different cores so that a small number of request processing threads can manage a large number of concurrent requests without ever waiting on a CPU core.

Is this a correct general understanding?

**Q2. How the callback works ?**

In the above scenario - `Thread B` that is doing the I/O work will run the callback function (provided by Thread A) if/when the I/O work has completed - which completes the `Future` with some Result.

Thread A is now off doing something else and has no association any more with the original request. How does the Result in the Future get sent back to the client socket? I understand that different languages have different implementations of such a mechanism but at a high level my current assumption is that (regardless of the language/framework) some framework/container objects must always be doing some sort of orchestration so that when a Future task is completed the Result gets sent back to the original socket handling the request.

---

I have spent hours trying to find articles which will explain this but every article seems to just deal with real low-level details. I know Im missing some details but i am having difficulty asking my question because Im not quite sure which parts Im missing :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> My understanding of non-blocking architectures is that the common approach is to still have some Thread waiting/blocking on the I/O work somewhere

If a thread is getting blocked somewhere, it is not really a non-blocking architecture. So no, that's not really a correct understanding of it. That doesn't mean that this is necessarily bad. Sometimes you just have to deal with blocking (using JDBC, for example). It would be better to push it off into a fixed thread pool designated for blocking, rather than allowing the entire application to suffer thread starvation.

> Thread A is now off doing something else and has no association any more with the original request. How does the Result in the Future get sent back to the client socket?

Using `Future`s, it really depends on the `ExecutionContext`. When you create a `Future`, where the work is done depends on the `ExecutionContext`.

```
val f: Future[?] = ???
val g: Future[?] = ???
```

`f` and `g` are created immediately, and the work is submitted to a task queue in the `ExecutionContext`. We cannot guarantee which will actually execute or complete first in most cases. What you do with the values matters is well. Obviously if you use an `Await` to wait for the completion of the `Future`s, then we block the current thread. If we `map` them and do something with the values, then we again need another `ExecutionContext` to submit the task to. This gives us a chain of tasks that are asynchronously getting submitted and re-submitted to the executor for execution every time we manipulate the `Future`.

Eventually there needs to be some `onComplete` at the end of that chain to return the pass along that value to something, whether it's writing to stream, or something else. ie., it is probably out of the hands of the original thread.

Comment: m-z, thanks very much for the comments. I get 1. but am still missing something on 2. I have a better understanding of Future  and ExecutionContext now thanks. I think my problem is at a higher-level perhaps ie. how does the result of a successfully completed Future object on the heap result in an outputstream? - I guess there is some Response object bound to the original Future which causes the outputstream to be written back out thru the socket of the server. Im using Play/Netty so I guess I need to check the docs.

Answer (score 5):

Q1: No, at least not at the user code level. Hopefully your async I/O ultimately comes down to an async kernel API (e.g. `select()`). Which in turn will be using DMA to do the I/O and trigger an interrupt when it's done. So it's async at least down to the hardware level.

Q2: Thread B completes the `Future`. If you're using something like `onComplete`, then thread B will trigger that (probably by creating a new task and handing that task off to a thread pool to pick it up later) as part of the completing call. If a different thread has called `Await` to block on the `Future`, it will trigger that thread to resume. If nothing has accessed the `Future` yet, nothing in particular happens - the value sits there in the `Future` until something uses it. (See `PromiseCompletingRunnable` for the gritty details - it's surprisingly readable).

Comment: Imm, thanks for your comments. As in my comment to m-v above, Im still not quite understanding how a completed Future results in an outputstream - but then this is a bigger question than just callbacks I guess.

Comment: `Future` has no particular connection to `OutputStream`. In the case of Spray (which I'm more familiar with) there's not even an `OutputStream` involved - it uses an actor that ultimately talks to the nio API.